# Flexbox vertical align some elements at top, some elements at the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an image of what I'm trying to create with HTML/CSS.  I've looked into flexbox a little bit.  I don't want to explicitly set the height of the text div.

I have a jsfiddle of where I'm currently at - http://jsfiddle.net/wxc0jmjw/1/ (there's no images in the js fiddle)  Basically, I just need some text at the top of a container, some at the bottom, and the height to be variable based on the height of the contents.  Any help is appreciated!

```
.flexbox-container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.flexbox-vert-item {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flexbox-vert-item2 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.demo-wrapper {
  min-height: 500px;
}

<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item2">SOme text at the top</div>
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item">Blah blah 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123     123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123     123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123     123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item2">SOme text at the top</div>
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item">Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: Diagram of what I'm trying to create]

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes to your CSS (and removed vendor prefixed `flexbox` properties for simplicity). The following modifications were required:

- Remove `-webkit-align-items: center;` to allow `.wrapper` to fill the full height of `.flexbox-container`
- Make the children in `.wrapper` use flexbox by adding `display: flex;` to `.wrapper`
- Make the children in `.wrapper` sort from top to bottom by adding `flex-direction: column;` to `.wrapper`
- Allow the `.flexbox-vert-item2` to grow and take up the available space by adding `flex: 1;` to `.flexbox-vert-item2`

```css
.flexbox-container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexbox-vert-item {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.flexbox-vert-item2 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
.demo-wrapper {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item2">SOme text at the top</div>
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item">Text at the bottom Blah blah 123 123 123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 12123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 1233123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123123 123 123 123 123123 123</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item2">SOme text at the top</div>
    <div class="flexbox-vert-item">Text at the bottom Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ek38ff5r/4/

Comment: Hi, Thanks!  I added some more text to check though and it doesn't seem like the second div's text is anchored at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/dbzqv4hc/

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the code to take this into account. Please take another look.